# Will stringhttpmessageconverter override the content type of the response in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using LiferayPortal with Spring. My Spring Action class is having "json" as the content type in response. As per my requirement the content type should be "text/html". I have used the below code which did not work. I When i googled in some of the sites it is mentioned that we should use stringhttpmessageconverter.

But i did not get enough sites on how to use the class.Can i override stringhttpmessageconverter  in the same action class itself is that fine ?

```
@RequestMapping(value="view",  produces= MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
```

Comment: isnt that Spring Webflow? did you ensure that your code is going via your method above?

Comment: Yes my code is going through the above method